# electron react boilerplate playwright

Tags: reactjs, electron, cypress, testcafe, playwright

I'm using [electron react boilerplate](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/), and i'm looking for a way to do automated e2e test, i don't have any experience in testing, i have been playing around with testcafe and got it to work, but my issue with test cafe that it doesn't support multiple windows on electron( as far as my research and tries go),
now i'm thinking about checking out playwright since it has many features that would be nice to have like test recording and multiple windows, i tried following the tutorial but with no luck.

my main issue that i want to be able to run tests while i'm in development before packaging the app. be it with test cafe, playwright or cypress.

Comment: TestCafe supports multiple windows if they are opened in the renderer process (like `window.open(url, '_blank')`. Could you please share with us a code snippet illustrating how it is implemented in your app?

Comment: that's the issue they aren't opened from the renderer process, i have 3 windows that i hide show based on what the user wants, i create them with Browserwindow constructor

Comment: At present, windows opened using the BrowserWindow constructor are not supported.
You can create an issue in the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron/issues repository and add the 'enhancement' label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test with playwright, it's nice and has a somewhat small learning curve.
i'm using electron-react-boilerplate as a base for my project and developing only for windows

[use this to install playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro)

because my installer installs other things on first install, i need to package the app,and then install it, to be able to test it.

```
test.describe('First Window Tests', async () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    ElectronAppController.electronApp = await electron.launch({
      executablePath: 'C:\\pathTo\\app.exe',
    });
 });
}
```

thanks to the testcafe team, it was nice using it, and i hope you will add support for electron in the testcafe studio in the future :).